# How to see a generic method's return type without using mouse in IntelliJ/Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I want my IDE (android studio/intellij) to tell me the return type of `T` for a method like `.asObservable<T>`.

The below image pops up when I **⌘+click** a method. This is perfect, ***except I have to use a mouse***, slowing me down.

Is it possible to achieve this effect ***without*** using a mouse? I would like to trigger this popup based on the ***current position of my cursor***.

[image]

References:

[IntelliJ Mac Keymap](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf)

[IntelliJ Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-to-declaration-or-type-declaration-of-a-symbol.html)

Comment: Command+P should give you the same information (or rather similar information - the types are shown using simple names instead of fully qualified names as shown in your screenshot)

Comment: That only gives information on parameters, I'm interested in the return type

Comment: Then try enabling _Show full signatures_ in _Parameter info_ section of _Settings/Editor/General/Code completion_ :)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable *Show full signatures* in *Settings/Editor/General/Code completion* which will make <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> popup show full signature including return type instead of just parameters.

---

[image]